# In Mercurial, is it possible to export a file from a given commit?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Let's say I have a file `main.c` that I have been coding on. I am already on commit #100 but unfortunately I discovered I need to recover some functions I had coded in commit #50. I know I can use the Repository Explorer to see the differences between different versions on this file, but what I'd like to see is the file itself, as it was on commit #50 (without all those +'s and -'s -- just the file as it was at that time).

Is that possible?

I wouldn't want to have to make a commit to #50 just to get those functions and then have to go back to #100.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hg cat` will export the file. To commit on this revision, you need `hg up`. For example, use

```
hg cat -rC F
```

to retrieve revision C of file F.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get it. How can I tell hg to export file f of commit c?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

```
hg update -r 50 that_file
cp that_file /to/some/other/location/
hg update -r 100 ---> to get back the new file
```

Now you have two files

1. One in repo at revision 100
2. The other at /to/some/other/location/ at revision 50